# Using Ruby Pathname to access relative directory

Tags: ruby, path, pathname

Given I have a relative path pointing to a directory how can I use it with Ruby's Pathname or File library to get the directory itself?

`p = Pathname.new('dir/')`

`p.dirname => .`

`p.directory? => false`

I have tried './dir/', 'dir/', 'dir'.

What I want is p.dirname to return 'dir'. I do not want point to another file or directory within 'dir'.

Comment: `p.to_s`; `p.basename.to_s`

Comment: Obviously, I'm working on a generic solution that also needs to handle directories on base level. In a normal case dirname works fine (/etc/dir/file => /etc/dir) this is why I want to use that. to_s and basename make no sense in this case. The question clearly states my purpose, please do not downvote and give unrelated answers.

Comment: You want to use `dirname` to return something that's not the directory name? You need add another level like `p = Pathname.new('dir/.')` now the directory name is "dir"

Comment: Dirname returns what directory 'dir/' is in. I don't think what you're asking is very clear.

Comment: @John La Rooy: IMO 'dir/' clearly is a directory. But if it is not posibble wihtout addig another level then that answers my question, thank you. I'll accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: @PSkocik: I wanted to refer to dir as directory without adding another level (since I don't know what is inside), but '.' makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add another level like

```
p = Pathname.new('dir/.')
```

now the directory name is "dir"

Comment: Note that my original intention i.e. to do this without adding another level is not posibble with Pathname.

Answer (score 1):

File.expand_path(FILE)
 => "/tmp/somefile"

File.dirname(File.expand_path(FILE))
 => "/tmp"